# When creating a many to many relation with an attribute, should I include a non-composite primary key?

Tags: mysql, database-design, primary-key

For example, I have `frame` and `voltage` tables, both of which relate to a motor object:

```
frame(id, motor_attribute);
voltage(id, voltage_attribute);
```

I can pick a frame and pick a voltage and for each combination of those there is an assigned efficiency attribute.

I can thus create an efficiency table, but how?  I see two choices:

```
efficiency(frame_id, voltage_id, efficiency_attribute);
//composite key = (frame_id, voltage_id)
```

OR

```
efficiency(id, frame_id, voltage_id, efficiency_attribute);
//composite key = (frame_id, voltage_id)
//primary key = (id)
```

Do I include a non-composite primary key into the table?

Comment: Don't do anything without a reason.  A composite key is perfectly fine for this example.  Generally non logical keys should be avoided.  There are reasons to generate an identity based key or a random guid based key but it usually is when there is no logical value to use for the key.  That is not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

What are voltage and efficiency?  Simple numbers (`SMALLINT`) or `FLOATs`?  Then do not normalize them and do not use a many:many table.  Simply have the value in the table instead of an id pointing to the value.  There is such a thing as "over-normalization"; it does not scale well.

Use many:many mapping tables for relating things that have lots of attributes.

Back to your question...  A many:many table does not need a surrogate `id` for the PK.  It is not just OK to have a composite PK, it is actually more efficient to have such.  Save `AUTO_INCREMENT` for cases where there is no good "natural PK".

Other [*tips*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) on many:many tables.  Note that it advises having a secondary key for when you need to 'go the other direction'.

(Based on Comment):

Using ENUMs:

```
voltage ENUM('unknown', "460/60/3", ...)  NOT NULL
efficiency ENUM('unknown', "ie1", ...)  NOT NULL
```

Using a string:

```
voltage VARCHAR(15)   CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
efficiency VARCHAR(8) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
```

Normalizing:

```
voltage_id TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ... and another table
efficiency_id ...
```

If there are very few choices, and the list of choices changes only very rarely, `ENUM` may be optimal.  The 'string' option is not too bad since the strings are rather short.  I feel that the normalizing is "over-normalizing" in this case, namely only a few short strings.

Comment: voltage in my case is a description string, such as "460/60/3" (voltage, hz, phase).  Efficiency is a string such as "ie1".  There are only three of each, so a cross-product will produce 9 values.  Are you suggesting just creating a single table that contains a cross-product of all those?

Comment: @Dennis - I added to my Answer.  I don't think I am recommending a cross-product.  As for the PK. we need to see not only the full table, but also some typical queries.